# Dismiss alert view when performing delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

hi there when i run my delegate method which is parsing json data the alert view appears to freeze whilst it is performing the method is there anyway to hide the alert view whilst the app is running the code I've tried

```
   - (IBAction)btnAdd:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Add Source" message:@"Enter the web address of the json data" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add", nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert setTag:0];
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
    [alert show];
}
```

this doesn't actually do anything. 
any advice?

*UPDATE
in the delegate method i get the same result

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (alertView.tag == 0) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            NSString *textEnteredraw = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
            [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
```

Comment: Where is `alert` declared?

Comment: Does `alert` have a non-nil value? Is that line called? Perhaps you should show more relevant code.

Comment: Advice - don't run your parsing code on the main thread...

Comment: @Wain I'm new to this do you mean to create a separate method?

Comment: @JordanNewton Please put the code in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry, sorted it :)

Comment: OK, why are you calling `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:` *before* showing the alert view?

Comment: i've tried it in the delegate method and got the same result

Comment: You haven't shown anything to do with the parsing, how does that code relate?

Comment: 1) Never use a tag of `0` since that is the default for all views. 2) There is no need to call `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex` from the delegate method. Alert views will be dismissed automatically when you tap a button.

Comment: I've achieved it by moving the parsing code to a separate selector then called it using `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(parseJSONData) withObject:nil]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From method

```
 - (IBAction)btnAdd:(id)sender
```

Remove

`[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];`

Because as @Dima said, you are dismissing the alertView before you are even showing it.

Comment: i have removed it now and moved it to the delegate method however its still causing the same issue

Comment: You mentioned that you are downloading data from server! It's normal for the alertView to freeze when you are downloading data in sync. If you are downloading data that way, your alertView will wait for the operation of downloading to finish. Show me more code, and Ill give you feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You call the code to hide the alert before you even show it. This method is meant to be called after the alert is shown.